# Split dynamic array row data into column names in hive

Tags: hiveql

Problem statement: How to convert a row value, which has a dynamic array into column names in Hive.

Eg: table name: TAB1

## Col1     Col2

1. ```
    {a,b,c}
   ```
2. ```
    {a,b,d,e}
   ```
3. ```
    {e,c,a,m,n}
   ```

Required output: I somehow need to split the row data dynamic array into column names based on the Col1 as the filter on TAB1.

The Final query needs to be something like below ( i know some sort of JOIN to TAB1 is required)

```
select 1,a,b,c from TAB2;
select 2,a,b,d,e from TAB2;
select 3,e,c,a,m,n from TAB2;
```

Comment: can you please provide more details. It's confusing, do you have each row value with different array size ? or this apply to only header record ?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, each row could have a different array size. The elements in each array are column names on another table. So, the a,b,c,d,e,f,m,n are all columns in another table TAB2

Comment: Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

SELECT CONCAT("SELECT ",concat_ws(',', t.*)," FROM TAB2;") FROM TAB1;